# Is there a way to use Android's LifecycleObserver to notify about onActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-facebook, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-lifecycle

I currently use `LifecycleObserver` for notifying about events such as `onStart` of my view. This is great for components as presenters or handlers, such as `FacebookLoginHandler` that needs to register the callback once the view is ready. However, there are some situations, as the one I've mention, that I wanted my handler to handle the returned data of another activity.

**Example:**

When I choose to login with Facebook, it starts another activity and the return of it goes to view's `onActivityResult` method. this makes me inject my `FacebookLoginHandler` in the view, only to delegate the handling back to it. I wanted to use `LifecycleObserver` to get notified of `onActivityResult` and avoid having to couple my handler to the view only for delegating this event. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. I have "sign in with Facebook" functionality in my app and I want to move this functionality into separate class `AuthManager` that implements `LifecycleObserver`.

I have checked `Lifecycle.Event` class that contains all the available lifecycle events. Looks like at the moment (android.arch version 1.1.0) there is no event for hading `onActivityResult()` with `LifecycleObserver`.

Opened an issue about this: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/317

Comment: have you find solution to this ?

Comment: The issue was closed since it was opened on the samples project. I opened one in the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140476665

Comment: have you find solution to this?  (After 2 years)